# Outlook Web Add-in item move between folders event

Tags: graph, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Is there an event listener for items moved between folders? Like item1 moved from inbox to spam, or vice versa. I just want to run some logic on this event.

I know how to achieve this in VSTO add-in via `folder change` or `itemAdd` etc.

But the web add-in seems to be a different beast. The [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/) says "Extension points are the ways that add-ins integrate with Outlook. " Does it mean that web add-in does not support event listening?

Comment: Could you explain the scenario better? what specifically are you trying to do? from the sounds of it, using graph + notifications would be the right way to do this.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT. I just want to execute some business logic when user drag and drop their items from say inbox to another folder.So no buttons or UI needed. It is passive. I can find the sample code achieving this in VSTO, but in web add-in seems like I always need to create some buttons first.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Delta query is the best I can come up with Graph, it only tells me the newly added items when I do the query, it wont allow me to run some codes when addition occurs.

Comment: Check out change notifications here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/webhooks. That will let you know when a message is moved. You can then execute whatever code you want on your service. Web add-ins are not the right way to do this scenario - they're not meant for doing passive automation based on user events.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT thanks for the reply. I also thought that Web add-in is probably not the best choice for my requirement. So I opted for the VSTO template...